# Textarea Being Picky over Input

Tags: mysql, text, area

In my text area:

```
 <textarea  rows="12" cols="76" name="Skills" input id = "Skills" placeholder="Skills:" class = "textbox"  ><?php echo $skills; ?> </textarea>
```

It is being picky over what it accepts. For example it wont accept apostrophe's on its own line and it wont accept a bunch of commas on its own line. How can I make the text box so it will accept everything? Note: The characters can be typed in, but it wont be saved in the mysql database.

Here is the code that I use to save the contents of the text area to the mysql database.

```
session_start();
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get data that sent from form 
$bio=$_POST['Bio'];


$sql = "UPDATE members SET Bio = '$bio' WHERE id = $id";


$result=mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();
header("location:UserProfileSettingsUpdated.php");
?>
```

Comment: How do you know that it won't be saved in the db?

Comment: I display the contents of the text area on a separate
 page plus I checked the db

Comment: I fear you concatenate a sql string without sanitizing the user input. Please show the code that saves the input to the database.

Comment: I am not sanatizing the string since I'm doing this for my own fun, but would this result in that error?

Comment: I made an edit the code is now up

Comment: `$bio = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Bio']);`

Comment: Thanks! Why does this command help?

Comment: It worked perfectly by the way!

Comment: @user3505931 because it sanitizes the input ...